# How do I pass an object of Azure Tags from parameter.json file to a bicep template?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I am very new to bicep so I need some help on how to pass an object of Azure Tags from a parameters.json file to my bicep file and my syntax is wrong so it throws this error.

New-AzDeployment: - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template parse failed: 'Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'tags'.'.

New-AzDeployment: The deployment validation failed

ResourceGroup.Bicep

```
targetScope = 'subscription'

param resourceGroupName string
param location string
param resourceTagsObject object

resource biceprg  'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' = {
  name: resourceGroupName
  location: location
  tags: resourceTagsObject
}
output rgName string = biceprg.name
```

ResourceGroup.parameters.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "resourceGroupName": {
        "value": "testingparameterfile"
      },
      "location": {
        "value": "canadacentral"
      },
      "resourceTagsObject": {
        "value": {
          "tags": [
            {
          "Environment": "Dev",
          "Project": "Tutorial"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is my deployment code

```
New-AzSubscriptionDeployment -TemplateFile ResourceGroup.bicep -TemplateParameterFile ResourceGroup.parameters.json -location "canadacentral"
```

New-AzDeployment: - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template parse failed: 'Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'tags'.'.

New-AzDeployment: The deployment validation failed

Answer (score 0):

Your `resourceTagsObject` parameter type is object as it should be but you have accidentally wrapped resourceTagsObject object on parameter file with an array and extra object.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "resourceGroupName": {
        "value": "testingparameterfile"
      },
      "location": {
        "value": "canadacentral"
      },
      "resourceTagsObject": {
        "value": {
          "Environment": "Dev",
          "Project": "Tutorial"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

should work. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources?tabs=bicep#arm-templates

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I'm a little new to declaring the object in json so thanks for the correction.

Comment: @tmitch87 you should mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your question